# Adding new column and inserting values to an exisitng excelsheet using SSIS/SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

I have an existing  excel template as like below :

DATE                    7/28/2016   7/29/2016     July       MTD     YTD

Call Activity

IB_Calls_Offered    22              29          52       52       52

IB_Calls_Answered   22              29          52       52       52

Sale                     6              3           9         9        9

Everyday when my SP get executed , I need to add a extra column (as Current Date) and fill the corresponding data.

Kindly Suggest me how to do it by using SSIS/SSRS

Comment: Please post your SP.

Comment: In my SP I am inserting and calculating the corresponding values of the Column List of the table.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Posting all of the information (e.g. the relevant section of your stored procedure) will give you a better chance of getting an answer. It's up to you.